Python-Polars: group_by a column have the remaining columns be combined into a struct field?
I have not found a way to group_by() a column and have a struct field for the new column.Here is a snippet of the dataframe:



Census_Tract
GEOID_Census
table_B24012
value




Census Tract 9…
04001942600
B24012_001E
32179.0


Census Tract 9…
04001942700
B24012_001E
33483.0


Census Tract 9…
04001944000
B24012_001E
33114.0


Census Tract 9…
04001944100
B24012_001E
26993.0


Census Tract 9…
04001944201
B24012_001E
33798.0


...
...
...
...


Census Tract 2…
56043000200
B24012_073E
-6.6667e8


Census Tract 3…
56043000301
B24012_073E
-6.6667e8


Census Tract 3…
56043000302
B24012_073E
-6.6667e8


Census Tract 9…
56045951100
B24012_073E
41042.0


Census Tract 9…
56045951300
B24012_073E
-6.6667e8



Essentially what I am trying to do is to group by Census_Tract and GEOID_Census. The columns table_B24012 and value should be combined into one column.
In other words I would like the data to be a struct object such that for each GEOID_Census I have one row value with potential a dictionary structure built into the new column. It would look something like this



Census_Tract
GEOID_Census
table_B24012




Census Tract 9…
04001942600
{"B24012_001E": 32179.0, "B24012_002E": ..., ...}


Census Tract 9…
04001942700
{"B24012_001E": 33483.0, "B24012_002E": ..., ...}


Census Tract 9…
04001944000
{"B24012_001E": 33114.0, "B24012_002E": ..., ...}


Census Tract 9…
04001944100
{"B24012_001E": 26993.0, "B24012_002E": ..., ...}


Census Tract 9…
04001944201
{"B24012_001E": 33798.0, "B24012_002E": ..., ...}



If there is a more efficient way to store it in the column, I am open to other ways. I am just trying to condense the information.
I have tried casting the two columns to a list and then struct, as well as just to a dictionary. Nothing has helped. Any ideas?  Thanks in advance!

So you want the values in table_B24012 to become "field names" in the struct? (keys) Is this in preparation for dumping to JSON?

@jqurious Yes, that is the goal. No, it is not in preparation for a JSON. I am wanting to avoid having Billions of rows of repeating data or billions of columns. The easiest way I could think of is utilizing struct fields that can then be exploded as needed. I have more data than just this. The end goal will be a ML model after I format the data as wanted.

Ah okay. I don't think Polars offers an easy way to do that, there's no real way to "merge" structs that I know of. It sounds like you want something similar to pivoting: df.pivot(index=["Census_Tract", "GEOID_Census"], columns="table_B24012", values="value")

I added an answer with some more info. Not sure if it's exactly what your'e after but it may serve as an example of how to display your question (Config/from_repr). Trying to get your sample data from the markdown table is quite awkward (read_clipboard sort of works, but cells are truncated) - if it's provided as a code example, it's much simpler for others to work with.

It sounds like you want something similar to a .pivot()
Data
# increase defaults
pl.Config(fmt_table_cell_list_len=10, fmt_str_lengths=100)

df = pl.from_repr("""
┌────────────────┬──────────────┬──────────────┬─────────┐
│ Census_Tract   ┆ GEOID_Census ┆ table_B24012 ┆ value   │
│ ---            ┆ ---          ┆ ---          ┆ ---     │
│ str            ┆ str          ┆ str          ┆ f64     │
╞════════════════╪══════════════╪══════════════╪═════════╡
│ Census Tract 9 ┆ 04001942600  ┆ B24012_001E  ┆ 11111.0 │
│ Census Tract 9 ┆ 04001942700  ┆ B24012_002E  ┆ 22222.0 │
│ Census Tract 9 ┆ 04001942600  ┆ B24012_002E  ┆ 33333.0 │
│ Census Tract 9 ┆ 04001942700  ┆ B24012_001E  ┆ 44444.0 │
│ Census Tract 9 ┆ 04001944100  ┆ B24012_001E  ┆ 55555.0 │
└────────────────┴──────────────┴──────────────┴─────────┘
""")

Pivot
df.pivot("table_B24012", index=["Census_Tract", "GEOID_Census"])

shape: (3, 4)
┌────────────────┬──────────────┬─────────────┬─────────────┐
│ Census_Tract   ┆ GEOID_Census ┆ B24012_001E ┆ B24012_002E │
│ ---            ┆ ---          ┆ ---         ┆ ---         │
│ str            ┆ str          ┆ f64         ┆ f64         │
╞════════════════╪══════════════╪═════════════╪═════════════╡
│ Census Tract 9 ┆ 04001942600  ┆ 11111.0     ┆ 33333.0     │
│ Census Tract 9 ┆ 04001942700  ┆ 44444.0     ┆ 22222.0     │
│ Census Tract 9 ┆ 04001944100  ┆ 55555.0     ┆ null        │
└────────────────┴──────────────┴─────────────┴─────────────┘

Struct
It's easy to create a struct from there if desired:
(df.pivot("table_B24012", index=["Census_Tract", "GEOID_Census"])
   .select(
       "Census_Tract", 
       "GEOID_Census", 
       table_B24012 = pl.struct(pl.exclude("Census_Tract", "GEOID_Census"))
   )
)

shape: (3, 3)
┌────────────────┬──────────────┬───────────────────┐
│ Census_Tract   ┆ GEOID_Census ┆ table_B24012      │
│ ---            ┆ ---          ┆ ---               │
│ str            ┆ str          ┆ struct[2]         │
╞════════════════╪══════════════╪═══════════════════╡
│ Census Tract 9 ┆ 04001942600  ┆ {11111.0,33333.0} │
│ Census Tract 9 ┆ 04001942700  ┆ {44444.0,22222.0} │
│ Census Tract 9 ┆ 04001944100  ┆ {55555.0,null}    │
└────────────────┴──────────────┴───────────────────┘

